# Magento: How to add a Secondary Menu?

Tags: magento, menu

I'm trying to add a secondary menu bar besides the main menu bar because I want to keep the main menu with all the categories listed and then an individual menu per website/store within the same magento shop. The theme I'm using already comes with a menu widget and I sort of accomplish what I wanted but I have a little CSS styling issue. let me explain.

In order to have two menus, I did the following.

1. Copied `community/Company/MenuWidget` to `local/MyCompany/MyMenuWidget`
2. replaced all the references in all the files found under **Block, Helper, etc, controllers, Model,** that pointed to `Company_MenuWidget` to `MyCompany_MyMenuWidget`. I basically cloned the Menu Widget.
3. Added the following lines to `css.xml` under

> < reference name="header" >
>
> < block type="cms/block" name="cms_my_menu_block" >
>
> < action method="setBlockId" >< block_id>my_menu_block < /block_id ><
>   /action> < /block>

1. Added the following line to **header.phtml**

> < div class="my-class" >< ?php echo
>   $this->getChildHtml('cms_my_menu_block') ?>< /div>

1. Added a class to the CSS styles sheet 'my-class' with the same values of the nav-container class and then modified the valued to position the menu where I wanted it.
2. duplicated the MenuWidget styles sheet and renamed it as needed.
3. Created a block with the identifier for the store/website I wanted it to show up and it did.

Now the problem I'm facing is that the original menu is partially picking up the copied styles sheet so modifications I do to the copy, is partially affecting the main, not all the modifications. For example, I was able to move the container down and position it but now the "dropdown pop-ups" which I had to reposition as well, are being affected on both menus when I move them.

How can I completely separate the style sheets? I'm not even sure why the other menu bar is picking up on the new style sheet.

Any help is appreciated it.

Comment: which are you using which comes with secondary menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the "other" menu is reacting to both stylesheets is because both stylesheets are loading and you probably didn't change the classes/ids.  You can remove the other one using your local.xml probably in the default reference:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/path/to.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

A beter way to handle this would be to let the other menu do its thing and override the parts you want to with your own module.  I think how to do that is out of the scope of this/any answer, though.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your second advise. I let the menu do its thing and I attempted to override parts by adding new classes to the CSS style sheet and using those classes in my header.phtml where I inserted the new block and I played around with the positioning. It's not exactly what I wanted to do but for now it's serving its purpose.

the strange thing is that my module and the other menu's module call for its own stylesheet.

Comment: by calling it from the company_menu.xml found in the layout folder where mycompany_menu.xml is also found pointing to my own stylesheet.

'<reference name="head" module="company_menu">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/company_menu.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
</default>'

'<reference name="head" module="mycompany_menu">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/mycompany_menu.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
</default>'

but as I mentioned, it's only picking up parts of each.

Comment: How do you know it's only using parts of each?

Comment: Because I'm using firefox "Inspect Element" to view the styles and what files are being used on the styling. I also try to do some editing using the element inspector to see what gets affected when I change a value on the stylesheet and when I make those changes on the stylesheet, I can see that only a few parts affect both menus, not all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=2; 
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$categories = $catagory_model->load($id);
if(!empty($categories))
{
    $cats = explode(",", $categories->getChildren());
    foreach($cats AS $c)
{
    $cat = $catagory_model->load(trim($c));
    echo '<a href="/'.$cat->getUrlKey().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
}
}
```

This worked for me with the Core 1.9 Magento Setup in my /html/footer.phtml template file